# Erro ao gerar projeto jar

Tags: java, maven

Eu queria gerar um JAR do projeto que fiz no maven(simples). Mas gera esse erro. Por que gerou esse erro?

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ teste-MODEL ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [teste-MODEL] in [C:\Users\ooo\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.6.4.RELEASE\teste-   MODEL\target\teste-MODEL-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\ooo\Documents\workspace-ggts-  3.6.4.RELEASE\teste-MODEL\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [50 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\ooo\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.6.4.RELEASE\teste-MODEL\target\teste-MODEL-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] Total time: 3.480 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-10T01:06:15-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project teste-MODEL: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: jar. :D Vou dormir, detalho mais tarde.

Comment: Inclua seu `pom.xml`. Pelo log, o *packaging* do seu projeto é `war`, pode tentar apenas removendo o elemento `<packaging />`

Comment: Juntamente com o `pom.xml`, inclua também o `web.xml` do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua aplicação não usa web.xml por algum motivo (servlet 3.0 por exemplo), você pode ignorar a validação desse arquivo.

Adicione o código abaixo na seção **plugins** do seu pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Retirado [desse link do stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351948/webxml-attribute-is-required-error-in-maven)